# People arranged in a queue different approach

Tags: probability, combinatorics

People $O_1 \ldots O_{10}$ were arranged in a queue:
Find the probability that $O_1$ is in front of $O_2$ and in front of $O_3$
The answer is:
$$\frac{\binom{10}{3} \times 2  \times 7!}{10!}$$
My question is where does the 2 factor comes from? Why to include that 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose we are talking about 10 people here.

So there are $10!$ ways to put them in a row, which accounts for the $10!$ in the denominator. We pick three places for $O_1, O_2, O_3$, this can be done in $10 \choose 3$ ways. Then $O_1$ has to be in the foremost of these places, as he must be before $O_2$ and before $O_3$. So no choice there. But $O_2$ and $O_3$ can be in any order on the two remaining places, so there are 2 ways to do that. Finally we arrange the 7 other people in $7!$ ways as well.

Answer (score 2):

Take any permutation of the ten people.  Say that two such are equivalent if they differ by a permutation of $O_1,O_2,O_3$.  Clearly there are exactly $6$ members of each equivalence class.  Of these $6$ exactly two have the property you want (namely the ones with order $O_1,O_2,O_3$ and $O_1,O_3,O_2$.)

Hence the answer is $\frac 13$

Note:  To answer the question "Why to include that $2$?" the answer is "because there are exactly $2$ acceptable permutations of the three chosen individuals.  Absent the factor of $2$, the formula gives the probability that the three individuals occur in one specific order.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, actually he was asking *"Why to include that 2?"*

Comment: It's an elegant and correct answer, but does not answer the OP's question, I think.

Comment: @Marine1 The two arises because there are two acceptable permutations of the three elements.  I'll edit my post to clarify that.

Comment: @lulu, okay ;) can you clarify why "two such are equivalent if they differ by a permutation of $O_1,O_2,O_3$"? and why are there only $6$? I thought there was $9$ permutations of three elements...

Comment: @Marine1  Three elements can be permuted in 6 ways: three choices for the first, then two for the second (last is then determined). As to the equivalence, that's my definition. We need to do a count over all the permutations...I group them in sextuples and argue that exactly two choices from each sextuple get the job done.

Comment: @lulu God, sorry, I got terribly wrong! Yes, thanks putting me back on the right track

Comment: @Marine1 No problem.